# why calling super giving issue while callin in child class constructor?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Why its saying

error      `No enclosing instance of type Demo is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation`

```
class Demo {
    
    class DemoInner{
        
        DemoInner(){
            
            System.out.println("DemmoInner");
        }
        
    }

}


public class Noding extends Demo.DemoInner{

    Noding(){
        
        super();
        System.out.println("Noding");
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new Noding();
        
    }
}
```

`Noding` is a child of `Demo.DemoInner` and `Demo.DemoInner` is an instance thing of `Demo` class.

So while creating Child class `Noding` instance, calling `super` should not be giving a problem becasue parent should be in existence before creating child.  And in this case parent is `Demo.DemoInner` for `Noding` and `Demo.DemoInner` can't exist without `Demo`.

So why its giving error while calling `super()` in `Noding` constructor ?

Comment: Make DemoInner a static class

Comment: @RobOhRob solution is fine, am asking the reason why its happeing ?

Comment: Because without it being a static class, DemoInner is only available `within an instance of` Demo.

Comment: @RobOhRob, that's a point ..if this is case "DemoInner is only available within an instance of Demo"..then why calling super() pops up with a error in Noding class's constructor ?

Comment: The error is not on super, the error is on `extends Demo.DemoInner`

Answer (score 1):

The call to the inner class is called like this:

```
class Noding extends Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Demo demo = new Demo();
        Demo.DemoInner inner = demo.new DemoInner();

        System.out.println(inner);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice would be to add _a Demo.DemoInner` object has a `Demo.this` accessing its embedding Demo object. If `Demo.this` is not needed make DemoInner static._

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is declared as `static`, it is *dynamic*, that is the object needs to be instantiated.

If you declared DemoInner like this:

```
class Demo {
    class DemoInner{}
}
```

It means DemoInner class is one of the instances of Demo. So when you use DemoInner class, you need to instantiate Demo class first. And access DemoInner as the Demo instance's member object (see @AlexeyKonovalov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66775790/3501958)).

Or a workaround is to make DemoInner static (as @RobOhRob commented). Once declared static, it is no longer a member object of the outer class Demo object. You can access DemoInner class whether the outer class is instantiated or not.

```
class Demo {
    static class DemoInner{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making DemoInner as a static class shall make the code run. DemoInner is a non-static inner class and hence it is associated with the instance of Demo class.

You can't call its constructor from Noding without making the class static.

```
class Demo {
    static class DemoInner{        
        DemoInner(){
            System.out.println("DemmoInner");
        }
    } 
}

public class Noding extends Demo.DemoInner{
    Noding(){
        super();
        System.out.println("Noding");
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Noding();   
    }
}
```